# Show JFrame content when certain Combo Box item is chosen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcombobox

Is there a way to only show certain JFrame content only when an option in a Combo Box is chosen? I'm making an HTML editor and I want the user to choose what action they would like to perform on their HTML document.

Comment: Short answer - yes; Long answer - to many different ways to list, making the question to broad. I might consider using a `CardLayout` depending on what I was trying to achieve

Comment: A (simpler) alternate might be to put `Action` objects into a `JToolBar` and enable / disable them as needed.